# Disabled Spotlight indexing on USB drive and Finder search doesn't work on it

Tags: finder, usb, catalina, spotlight, indexing

I'm using macOS 10.15.4. I recently disabled Spotlight indexing on an external exFAT formatted USB drive with Tinkertool as it was reindexing every single time I connect it.

I thought that disabling indexing just meant that every time I would have used Finder search box I would have just ended up waiting for it to search the files by their name. Unluckily what happened is that search doesn't work **at all** on the drive.

Is there any way I can disable Spotlight indexing on the volume without losing Finder search function?

Thanks in advance.